# How to create a text file with specific text in it in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cat

I want to do this with 1 line of code :

Create a text file where 3 sentences underneath eachother are placed. I know the command to create an empty textfile it is "cat > sample.txt" but i want to create this file with these 3 sentences in it in one line of code. 
Like this :

```
sentence1
sentence2
sentence3
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
echo -e "sentence1 \nsentence2 \nsentence3" >> sample.txt
```

Comment: -e allows you to use the \n in the command to add a new line. http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/echo/